# How recyclerview onscroll works? Not getting expected result

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in my project, I have added a list of contacts in recyclerview using its adapter, in the onClick of its viewHolder I want to mark each position of my contact list as selected (I am using green color here to indicate selection), in order to do this I have tried the snippets below:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (selectedItems.get(getAdapterPosition(), false)) {
        selectedItems.delete(getAdapterPosition());
        view.setSelected(false);

        contacts_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        phone_number.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    } else {

        selectedItems.put(getAdapterPosition(), true);
        view.setSelected(true);
        contacts_name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        phone_number.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        Log.e("layout ", " Pos " + getLayoutPosition());
        Log.e("Adapter ", " Pos " + getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

selected items is a sparse Boolean Array to store the states of each position of contacts and I have used below drawable as background of my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/selector_green_bg" 
    android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/light_grey_color" 
    android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

OnBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ChooseOptionHolder holder, int position) {

    try {
        holder.contacts_name.setText(contact_name_list.get(position));
        holder.phone_number.setText(phone_nums.get(position));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Adapter class

```
public class ChooseOptionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChooseOptionHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> contact_name_list, phone_nums;
private Context context;
View layoutView;

ChooseOptionAdapter chooseOptionAdapter = this;

public ChooseOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> contacts_list, ArrayList<String> phone_num_list) {
    this.contact_name_list = contacts_list;
    this.phone_nums = phone_num_list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ChooseOptionHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.choose_contact_list, null);
    ChooseOptionHolder rcv = new ChooseOptionHolder(layoutView, chooseOptionAdapter);
    return rcv;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ChooseOptionHolder holder, int position) {

    try {
        holder.contacts_name.setText(contact_name_list.get(position));
        holder.phone_number.setText(phone_nums.get(position));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (holder.selectedItems.get(position)) {
        holder.itemView.setSelected(true);
        holder.contacts_name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        holder.phone_number.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
        holder.itemView.setSelected(false);
        holder.contacts_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        holder.phone_number.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    Log.e("boolean ", "array " + holder.selectedItems);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.contact_name_list.size();
}}
```

Adapter holder class

```
public class ChooseOptionHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    implements View.OnClickListener {

public TextView contacts_name;
public TextView phone_number;
int position;

public SparseBooleanArray selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
ArrayList<Boolean> status = new ArrayList<>();
ChooseOptionAdapter chooseOptionAdapter1;

public ChooseOptionHolder(View itemView, ChooseOptionAdapter chooseOptionAdapter) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    contacts_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_name);
    phone_number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    position=getAdapterPosition();

    if (selectedItems.get(position,false)){
        selectedItems.delete(position);
        view.setSelected(false);
        contacts_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        phone_number.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    } else {

        selectedItems.put(position,true);
        view.setSelected(true);
        contacts_name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        phone_number.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        Log.e("layout ", " Pos " + position);


    }

}
}
```

All this works perfectly but the problem is when I scrolls the view, some other positions of the view is already shown selected. I hope somebody can point out the mistake I have done.

Comment: where do you adding items in selectedItems?

Comment: else portion in the onClick method

Comment: It is due to your view item is recycled. It retain state of previous item you selected

Comment: i have same problem while using tint color over items , its repeating again without clicking on it.

Comment: what do you get in  Log.e("layout ", " Pos " + getLayoutPosition()); while scrolling ,every time new position?

Comment: @Gibs There are a few solutions you could try, like these: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724352/selected-items-in-recyclerview-change-on-scrolling), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018690/android-recyclerview-scrolling-changes-items), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200540/recyclerview-on-scrolling-values-changing-from-adapter). Recyclerview is great, but this is an issue that happens often.

Comment: @ Truong Giang Dam : How to handle this issue

Comment: look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (selectedItems.get(getAdapterPosition())) {
        selectedItems.delete(getAdapterPosition()); 
    } else {
       selectedItems.put(getAdapterPosition(), true); 
    }

   notifyItemChanged(int position) 
}
```

And

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ChooseOptionHolder holder, int position) {

    try {
         holder.contacts_name.setText(contact_name_list.get(position));
         holder.phone_number.setText(phone_nums.get(position));

         if(selectedItems.get(position)){
              view.setSelected(true);
              contacts_name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
              phone_number.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
         }else {
             view.setSelected(false);
             contacts_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
             phone_number.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: I understood the logic ,It works now ,but sometimes while scroll from down to top array is re initializing (I think so) ,selected positions could not retain.Any idea about it?

Comment: did you implement swipe to refresh ?

Comment: No i din't implemented.

Comment: update your full adapter code, please. I will check it out

Comment: I have updated my adapter and holder class please check it out.:) Thank you.

Comment: yeah, I see, try to declare selectedItems as a field of ChooseOptionAdapter instead of ChooseOptionHolder.

Comment: Thank you @Truong Giang Dam, simple mistake by me ,thanks to point out.